# Change canvas data source using processingjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, processing

At the moment, I am using processingjs for sketches on a canvas.
But as of right now, I want to make it possible to click on a button that changes the sketch in the canvas.
So I though I might be able to pull this off by changing the data source using jQuery.
Well, that doesn't work as processing only reads the pde file at load.
So here's my code:
HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script src="processing.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas">
            <canvas id="canvas1" data-processing-sources="anything.pde"></canvas>
        <div id="buttons">
            <div>
                <button id="clickMe">?</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
      change();
    });

function change() {

    $('#canvas1').remove();

    $( "#canvas" ).append("<canvas id='canvas2' data-processing-sources='other.pde'></canvas>");

}


});
```

and then the PDE file:

```
void setup()
{
    size(300, 300);
    background(1000);
    fill(255);
    noLoop();
    PFont fontA = loadFont("courier");
    textFont(fontA, 14);  
}

void draw(){  

    text("Hello Web!",20,20);
    println("Hello ErrorLog!");
    ellipse(20, 20, 20, 20);
}
```

So I was hoping for this to work but I read that it draws on page load.

So how can I achieve this? How can I make it so that a button click can change the sketch?
I've come to SO for this as I do not really understand what the processingjs website is telling me.
Does anyone know how to do this? I would appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Doing a search for "data-processing-sources" returns a ton of results. Please try them. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131427/873165) looks especially promising.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load processing.js sketch with ajax on user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100956/load-processing-js-sketch-with-ajax-on-user-click)

Comment: @KevinWorkman Very much thanks!! That answer worked like a charm!